# Detect Smart TV

Tags: browser-detection

Is there any script to detect if the site accessed starting this coming from a Smart TV?

I would like to detect whether a computer, tablet, mobile phone or TV. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Every http request sends a piece of information in its headers called ***user agent***, which identifies the browser being used. You should google for that.

Comment: are u using samsung smart tv or some other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as most smart TVs use the major browser projects (such as Mozilla, Chromium, Safari etc) as their web browser, you are not going to find much difference in their behavior if at all. Your only good solution is to rely on the courtesy of the browser to provide this information to you via the `user-agent` property of the header.

You can consult [this list of smart TV user agents](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list/device-detail?device=Smart%20TV) to engage at your detection strategy.

Comment: Wow, nice answer with that link! +1

Comment: Anyone know how to detect if access is from a computer, mobile/tablet, or smart tv?

Comment: Very nice answer!!

Answer (score 4):

Refer to BBC talframework http://fmtvp.github.io/tal/getting-started/introducing-tal.html

In this framework they are using detection method for the device, Once device is detected then js according to the framework is loaded

Answer (score 1):

You can try this service http://web.wurfl.io/#learnmore
But this service is free for limited requests